# How do I configure log4net for a different level for some classes?

Tags: configuration, log4net

I want INFO for everything and DEBUG for one package. I've tried numerous variations of:

```xml
<log4net>
    <appender name="RollingFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
        <param name="File" value="C:/temp/AutoTag.log"/>
        <param name="AppendToFile" value="true"/>
        <param name="MaxSizeRollBackups" value="2"/>
        <param name="MaximumFileSize" value="100KB"/>
        <param name="RollingStyle" value="Size"/>
        <param name="StaticLogFileName" value="true"/>
        <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
            <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d [%t] ac.server %-5p %c - %m%n"/>
        </layout>
    </appender>
    <root>
        <level value="INFO"/>
        <appender-ref ref="RollingFileAppender"/>
    </root>
    <logger name="AutoTagCore.net.windward.autotag.utils">
        <level value="DEBUG"/>
    </logger>
</log4net>
```

But nothing works. If I remove the `<root/>` part, I get the detailed in the one package. Otherwise it's as though the `<logger/>` part is not there.

How can I accomplish this? (**Updated** to show full log4net part).

**Update2:** I'm an idiot - I had the wrong package name in there.

Comment: Are you sure the AutoTagCore.net.windward.autotag.utils part is correct? Note GetLogger is case sensitive.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Logger will inherit all appenders from root. You need to specify level only:

```xml
<root>
    <level value="INFO"/>
    <appender-ref ref="RollingFileAppender"/>
</root>
<logger name="AutoTagCore.net.windward.autotag.utils">
    <level value="DEBUG"/>
</logger>
```

*BTW* Verify appender settings - it could be restricted to INFO level:

```xml
<threshold value="INFO"/>
```

And last possible issue - you can have different type namespace and logger name (maybe some typo).

Comment: @DavidThielen can you provide appender configuration? Or just verify if there is some threshold specified.

Comment: I just edited it to show the full log4net part. No threshold.

Comment: @DavidThielen verify that class which you are trying to log has namespace `AutoTagCore.net.windward.autotag.utils` (no typos!) If there is some typo in namespace name, then root logger is used.

Comment: Verified. If I remove the <root> part then it logs just the classes in that package so it must be valid.

Comment: Does the INFO in root override the DEBUG in logger?

Comment: @DavidThielen nope, setting in logger sets effective level of logger (i.e. overrides root settings)

Comment: There is also top-level threshold setting `<log4net threshold="WARN">` verify this setting also (you don't have it in your config sample, but maybe you copy-pasted just part of config)

Comment: @DavidThielen thanks for accepting! did you find the source of problem?

Comment: Yep - I copied the package for a different class - you were right that it was the package.

Comment: "Logger will inherit all appenders from root." - unless you explicitly tell it not to, using the attribute "additivity='false'" on a logger element.  Which can be very useful in some situations.